# Подключится к БД из класса наследника

Tags: python, ооп, классы, методы, type-error

Есть два класса:

```
class Connect():
    def __init__(self, host, user, password):
        try:
            self.dbconnector = mysql.connector.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=password, database=user)
            self.cursor = self.dbconnector.cursor()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Ошибка подключения к БД:\n%s" % (e))


class Users(Connect):
     def select_user_column(self, select):
        try:
            sql = "SELECT `%s` FROM `users`" % (select, self.user_id)
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            result = self.cursor.fetchone()
            self.cursor.close()
            resturn result
        except Exception as e:
            return "Ошибка выборки поля пользователя:\n%s" % (e)
```

Я создаю подключение к бд примерно таким образом:

```
connect = Connect('host.com', 'database_name', 'mypassword123')
```

После пытаюсь вызвать метод второго класса (выборка поля пользователя):

```
select = Users.select_user_column('name')
```

Но у меня ничего не выходит.

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'host', 'user', 'password'
```

Что я делаю не так? Хотелось бы один раз подключаться и пользоваться методами наследников.

Comment: у вас в коде mysql.connector.connect, 4 входных параметра, а при вызове вы передаете только 3

Comment: там у двух одинаковое название, с этим проблем нет

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: это полный текст ошибки, выше только номер строки, которая ее вызывает select = Users.select_user_column('name')

Answer (score 0):

У вас опечатка в слове password

```
mysql.connector.connect(host=host, user=user, ***passwd***=password, database=user)
```

Comment: неа, с этим все ОК, там и должен быть passwd